# Delphi7 + indy 10 imap получение тела письма с простым текстом

Tags: delphi, text, imap, indy

Задача - получить тело сообщения с ящика mail.ru
пишу:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button_testimapClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MsgCnt, i: integer;
  msg: TIdMessage;
begin
  try
    LoadMailSettings('imap');
    msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    msg.CharSet := 'windows-1251';
    msg.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset="windows-1251"';
MainImap.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(MainImap);
MainImap.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
MainImap.Connect;

MainImap.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
MsgCnt := MainImap.MailBox.TotalMsgs;

for i := MsgCnt downto 1 do
begin
  MainImap.Retrieve(i, msg);
  if msg.Subject <> '' then
  begin
    Memo_mail.Lines.Add(msg.Subject);
    Memo_mail.lines.AddStrings(msg.Body);
  end;

end;

MainImap.Disconnect;
MainImap.IOHandler.Free;
msg.free;


except
    on e: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error!');
  end;

end;
```

Все работает без ошибок ибо тут их невозможно сделать.
НО! у меня в ящике есть письма в формате html типа рассылок mail.ru и их тело из msg.Body прекрасно добавляется в мемо -т.е. чтение есть. ок.

Шлю письмо с gmail ящика себе с обычным текстом, получаю его, делает msg.Body и пустота. 
Где я накосячил?

Comment: ну и в догонку- служебные заголовки на почтовике подсказали что multipart/alternative у него сидит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из справки indy: When `ContentType` contains a value in the `"multipart/*"` MIME family, use `MessageParts` to access the `TIdText` or `TIdAttachment` instances that make up the message.
Т.е. Вам надо использовать msg.MessageParts

Comment: Тоже дошел до этого. вот что получилось `for j:=0 to msg.MessageParts.Count-1 do
          begin
            (msg.MessageParts[j] as TIdText)`     дальше не пойму что брать

Comment: Примерно так: `if msg.MessageParts.TextPartCount > 0 then
                begin
                  for PartIndex := 0 to msg.MessageParts.Count - 1 do
                    if msgObject.MessageParts[PartIndex] is TIdText then
Memo_mail.lines.AddStrings(TIdText(msg.MessageParts[PartIndex]).Body.Text);
                end
                else
                  Memo_mail.lines.AddStrings(msg.Body.Text);`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!